# CSS outline around button not working on iPad Chrome

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, angular, outline

I'm displaying a manual 'selected-for-editing' outline around a button using CSS. (The user clicks on the button to select it, then uses up/down arrows elsewhere on the page to change the value displayed on the selected button. There are many buttons the user can edit in a grid.)

CSS 'outline' works fine in Chrome on a PC, but doesn't display anything in Chrome on an iPad (IOS 10). Can anyone suggest CSS that will make it work on the iPad?

Angular2 :

```
<button class='rtb-btn btn-{{this.state}}'  (click)='this.incrementState()' (blur)='this.onBlurTemplateButton($event)'>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-calculated:focus           { outline: 0; }
.btn-calculated-selected:focus  { outline: 1; outline-color: black }
.btn-forced:focus               { outline: 0; }
.btn-forced-selected:focus      { outline: 1; outline-color: black }
.btn-editing-selected:focus     { outline: 1; outline-color: black }
.btn-locked:focus               { outline: 0; }
```